# Significado como jerga de "checar el aceite"

Tags: expresiones, coloquialismos, méxico, letras-de-canciones

Me gustaría saber cuál es el significado de la expresión ***checar el aceite***. Entiendo que es mexicana, aunque también puede que se use en otros países de latinoamérica en su forma de jerga.

Entiendo que ha de tener que ver con algo de índole sexual.

Para mayor contexto, la expresión está en la canción de Molotov [*Quitate Que Ma'sturbas (Perra Arrabalera)*](https://www.letras.com/molotov/26646/):

> Pensaste que yo quería contigo
>   Buscando el anillo que se le perdió a un amigo
>   No sabes ni cuánto me divierte
>   Que me quieras tanto por **checarte el aceite**

En ese contexto no creo que tenga nada que ver con algo como "comprobar los niveles de aceite de un coche", que es el significado más habitual sin jerga.

Comment: Supongo que se refiere al coito porque cuando se chequea el nivel de aceite en un auto, hay algo que sugiere la forma del pene que se mete en algo que sugiere la forma de vagina.

Comment: ¿Es de índole sexual? Cierto. ¿Se refiere al coito? Cierto. Para entenderlo basta con hacer una analogía de los elementos requeridos para revisar el aceite de un auto.

Answer (score 6):

Claramente tiene una connotación: penetrar con el pene y, de forma más genérica, fornicar, follar, hacer el amor...

Cuando uno quiere mirar el nivel de aceite del motor, lo que hace es introducir una varilla muy fina en el depósito y después ver cuánto ha quedado mojado:

> [image]

Véase por ejemplo [un vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SyFuFTxkwEA) en el que documentan cómo se revisa el aceite... en un coche.

El paralelismo con la penetración con pene es bastante directo: lo que el grupo Molotov quiere decir con:

> No sabes ni cuánto me divierte
>   Que me quieras tanto por checarte el aceite

Es mostrar (además de un profundo desprecio) la sorpresa porque una chica quiera al protagonista de la canción, cuando este objeta que lo único que hace con ella es fornicar.

Publicado en Reddit, [me comentan](https://www.reddit.com/r/mexico/comments/86b12b/qu%C3%A9_significado_tiene_checar_el_aceite_en_una/dw3mkfs/) que *Sexo anal generalmente nunca va a involucrar excremento, pero existe en la imaginación ese idea que vas a insertar tu vara, sacarlo y ver hasta donde quedó manchado*. Por ello, este *checar el aceite* podría referirse al sexo anal. Sin embargo, me extrañaría la referencia tan explícita, dado que el resto de la canción no tiene referencias. Más bien al contrario, dice *Por ahí me dijo un fulano que ahora te gusta tambien por el ano ya no controlas tu calentura*, lo que descartaría que el autor de la canción se refiriera a ese tipo de sexo.

El uso de [*checar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8gRRZ3I) parece ser únicamente propio de México según el DLE (de todo Centroamérica [según el DAMER](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=checar)), donde se utiliza como sinónimo de [*chequear*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8hGjJNl), que a su vez es un anglicismo para designar *Examinar, controlar o cotejar algo*.

También recoge el DAMER otra acepción, esta únicamente propia de México:

> intr. Mx. Juntar, combinar adecuadamente una cosa con otra.

Comment: En Colombia usamos "medir el aceite" pero no tiene que ver con el acto sexual. En nuestro caso significa verificar el estado o disposition de una persona para algo. Ej: _Antes de pedir un aumento a mi jefe le pregunte por los resultados de su equipo favorito para **medirle el aceite** y ver si estaba de buen humor_. En inglés existe una igualita que es _to test the water(s)_

Comment: Que padre respuesta!

Comment: En Argentina también es "medir el aceite" pero el significado es, como en la respuesta, relativo al acto sexual. Ni qué decir tiene que el ejemplo que da @DGaleano ocasionaría un malentendido vergonzoso.

Comment: @pablodf76 bueno saberlo. Gracias.